# ERROR while trying to use crossmint credit card payment for collection created using crossmint API

Tags: crossmint

Hi I am trying to use crossmint credit card checkout service for a collection created using crossmint api provided in thier docs [api in doc](https://docs.crossmint.com/reference/create-collection).

But getting this error...
"Configuration error

Payments support isn't configured for this collection"[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZcT9.png)

this is the code used in react

```
<CrossmintPayButton
                collectionId="56a1afa2-f016-470d-9070-e0b817e3df20"
                projectId="b1bf2bc7-4160-4c7b-b8fd-f37b6d23a4d9"
                environment="staging"

            />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you're using our brand new managed contracts. Collections created via the API are not enabled for payments and only support use via our REST API.

You'll need to create the collection via our staging developer console to test the payments feature out with a managed collection.

https://staging.crossmint.com/console